# Decimal to UpperCase Hex String on Go

Tags: go, printf

I'm converting a Decimal to (a modified) Hex value within an fmt.Sprintf function as I form a long string with a for loop - But want the value to be UpperCase rather than LowerCase Hex. Where should this occur? In the Dec to Hex conversion? Or a modification of the strings.Join function?

```
for ....{
b := []string{}
b = append(b, fmt.Sprintf("[%d=%s]", m.K, fmt.Sprintf("%016x", m.V)[2:14]))}

fmt.Fprintf(
            outputFile,
            "%d, 0, %d, %s, 0\n",
        ..,
        ..,
        ..,
        strings.Join(b, " "))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [Package fmt](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/)
>
> import "fmt"
>
> Printing
>
> The verbs:
>
> String and slice of bytes:
>
> ```
> %x    base 16, lower-case, two characters per byte
> %X    base 16, upper-case, two characters per byte
> ```

For example,

```
fmt.Sprintf("%016X", m.V)[2:14]
```